# SonarQube Scanner analysis skipped in travis CI

Tags: analysis, skip, sonarqube-scan

---

Does anyone knows for which reasons a SonarQube Scanner analysis could be skipped ?

```
$ sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.com -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN
08:59:10.162 INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
08:59:10.166 INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/travis/build/armadito/glpi/plugins/armadito/sonar-project.properties
08:59:10.182 INFO: SonarQube Scanner analysis skipped
The command "sonar-scanner -e -X -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.com -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN" exited with 0.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I found out that travis-ci's sonarqube addon set by itself the following environnment variable :

```
export SONARQUBE_SKIPPED=true
```

With the following message :

```
Skipping SonarQube Scan because this branch is not master or it does not match declared branches
```

Indeed, I was working on a different branch: *DEV*.

Thus, the solution is the following, in **.travis.yml** :

```
sonarqube:
    branches :
    - DEV
```

**And** in sonar-project.properties :

```
sonar.branch=DEV
```

Comment: I've added this to my yml file but it changed nothing. Do you have a suggestion on how to debug it?

Comment: There is actually a recent issue on github : https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6977

Comment: Try add sonar.branch=Your_branch in your sonarproject.properties.

Comment: the issue you posted offered the perfect solution

Comment: I'm not sure how the various config files hang together (and haven't read the docs, because I'm a bad person), but I don't have a sonar-project.properties file, and don't seem to need it; for me just adding my branch name to the .travis.yml was enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have added branch under addons in travis.yml and also sonar branch in sonar properties file, but still SonarQube analysis gets skipped. how to fix this?

addons:
sonarqube:
token:
secure: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
branches :

develop
added in travis.yml

and in sonar-project.properties, I have added this key as well
sonar.branch=develop

but travis has always this
$ export SONARQUBE_SKIPPED=true

0.41s$ sonar-scanner

INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/conf/sonar-scanner.properties

INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/........../sonar-project.properties

INFO: SonarQube Scanner analysis skipped