# Travis - INFO: SonarQube Scanner analysis skipped

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to add SonarQube analysis to our OSS Project with travis on Github.

I performed the following steps:

1. Create a organization and project on sonarcloud.io
2. Add the sonarcloud definition in `.travis.yml`
3. Create a `sonar-project.properties` file
4. Push everything to a feature branch called `feature/sonarcloud`
5. Add this branch to travis.yml and properties file.

The final result can be seen here:
https://github.com/open62541/open62541/tree/feature/sonarcloud

Unfortunately Travis does not submit the sonar analysis:

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file:
/home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner analysis skipped
```

(See also https://travis-ci.org/open62541/open62541/jobs/287631673)

I already tried to forcefully set `export SONARQUBE_SKIPPED=false` but it is still skipped. How can I find out why the scanner analysis is skipped?

---

Related questions:

- [SonarQube Scanner analysis skipped in travis CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607127/sonarqube-scanner-analysis-skipped-in-travis-ci)
- [Travis CI skipping SonarQube analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081020/travis-ci-skipping-sonarqube-analysis)

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the [Travis CI logs, at line 556](https://travis-ci.org/open62541/open62541/jobs/287631673#L556):

```
Skipping SonarCloud Scan because this branch is not master or it does not match declared branches
```

This is because you haven't activated analysis on that "feature/sonarcloud" branch. As described in the [official documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sonarcloud/#Activation-for-branches), you can achieve that like this:

```
  addons:
    sonarcloud:
      organization: open62541
      token:
        secure: "..."
      branches:
        - master
        - feature/sonarcloud
```

Comment: I already added the branch to the branches list. See: https://github.com/open62541/open62541/blob/feature/sonarcloud/.travis.yml#L64
Or am I missing something?

Comment: @SailAvid the branches key has the wrong level of indentation in the blob you link there. It sits beside sonarcloud, instead of beside organization and token.

Comment: Got it running. See: https://github.com/open62541/open62541/pull/1690/commits/ea95551d989892a48072bc353696f5b8538010c1